# CMake can't find file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm working on a CMake project with multiple subdirectories and I can't get it to work. My working directory is the following:

```
├───main.cpp
├───CMakeLists.txt
├───build
├───States
    └───CMakeLists.txt
└───Elevator
    ├───CMakeLists.txt
```

Once I build the project, I get `Elevator/Elevator.h: No such file or directory` as an error. The way my project is set up, Elevator is included in States and apparently CMake isn't linking them properly.

My root CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.4)
project(Test)
set(CMAKE_CPP_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CPP_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

add_subdirectory(Elevator)
add_subdirectory(States)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Elevator States)
```

The one in Elevator:

```
set(elevator_source_files
  Elevator.cpp
  Elevator.h
  Set.cpp
  Set.h
)

add_library(Elevator ${elevator_source_files})
```

The CMakeLists.txt in States:

```
set(state_source_files
  State.h
  State.cpp
  InitialState.h
  InitialState.cpp
  EmergencyState.cpp
  EmergencyState.h
  IdleState.h
  IdleState.cpp
  MaintenanceState.h
  MaintenanceState.cpp
  MovingState.h
  MovingState.cpp
  AllStates.h
  FSM.h
  FSM.cpp

)

add_library(States ${state_source_files})
target_include_directories(States PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/..)
target_link_libraries(States PUBLIC Elevator)
```

I'm still a novice so any help would be appreciated! It's worth noting that States.h includes Elevator with `#include "Elevator/Elevator.h"`

UPDATE: The project now builds and runs. I updated the CMake files in the description.

Comment: My #include "Elevator/Elevator.h" are indeed in State.h since State.h receives an instance of an Elevator as a parameter. Changing to that line in State's CMake won't work.

Comment: Change `target_include_directories(States PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})` to `target_include_directories(States PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/..)`

Comment: It works!!! Thanks so much!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `#include "Elevator/Elevator.h"` to work in the States library you need to include the folder containing the Elevator folder.

One way to fix this is to change

```
target_include_directories(States PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
```

to

```
target_include_directories(States PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} 
${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/..)
```

to have CMake add the State folder and its parent to the include directories.

Comment: On second thought `target_include_directories(States PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/..)` may be sufficient as you normally don't need to include the folder containing the source files.

Comment: While this works, the clean solution would had been to move the public headers of the `Elevator` library to a deeper subfolder (e.g. `Elevator/include/Elevator/`) and then to export `Elevator/include` as the public include directory from `Elevator`. So you don't end up with including *everything* even if you didn't even link the required library...

Comment: I usually separate my source and headers into separate folders (src and include) inside the folder for each library.

Comment: Your `Elevator` project may be a better place to add the `target_include_directories(Elevator PUBLIC  ...)`